# Android: Disabling/enabling connections (network, bluetooth) at a given time

Tags: android, service, background, task, scheduler

in order to save battery I'd like to switch off all connections (bluetooth, wifi, mobile network) and other power-consuming features at a given time (say 11 pm).

What is the best way to do this? I am thinking of a service that is started after booting so I do not have to restart the service manually. For the beginning I even don't need an app for the UI - I can hardcode the time for switching off. Maybe later it would be nice to be able to change the time via GUI but this is not really necessary.

So the only time the service needs to do something is at my desired time, however in order to detect the time it needs to run continously in the background without consuming too much energy.

What is the best way for this kind of job?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

You can send a repeating alarm that will trigger a service on a specific time of the day to do (or any actions you want). Please refer below for setting the time on a specific time:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(AndroidAlarmService.this, KillNetworkService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AndroidAlarmService.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23); //23 for 11pm
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

for my example, it will start the KillNetworkService.class everyday at 11pm, and from that service, you can now turn off your network.

Reference for alarm manager tutorial: 
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Comment: Hello Tenten Ponce,

thanks for providing an example and also the link to the tutorial. I've had a short look at the reference link and I think that's where I am heading for.

Comment: Happy to help. Sorry for the short answer a while ago.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I have run in another problem that killed my idea.
I wanted to switch off the mobile network or the airplane mode but Google decided long ago not to allow this anymore for unrooted devices. 

In order to change the airplane mode I would need to modify Settings.Global-settings which requires android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS-privlege which is only granted to system apps...

So the max I could do is to disable wifi and bluetooth - but these are off  anyway by default on my phone...

Too bad...

Comment: Yes as this may cause a security hole and also:

The reason to not allow apps to change this setting without a direct user involvement is to protect users from paying unexpected bills coming after malicious app "decides" to switch mobile data on while in roaming or for users without data flat rate.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20700138/9038584

However, you can still provide an OPTION if they are rooted using this code:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c svc data disable");

(Reference also on the link)